# Microsoft Access to SQL: Error 3027. Cannot update. Database or object is read-only

Tags: sql, ms-access

Microsoft Access just started throwing this error(3027) after I added a new column(!datTimeOn) to a table and re-linked the SQL Database.

I've Tried re-linking the database and nothing has happened. (The new column that was added isn't an identity column). The database and table are not read only and the user that is connected to the database has admin rights. Not sure what I'm missing but any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub Logon()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Dim DB As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set DB = CurrentDb
Set rs = DB.OpenRecordset("tblUserLogNew", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

'add and update user login info
With rs
  rs.AddNew
    !strUserID = (New_clsEnvironVariables.strUsername)
    !strAccessLogon = CurrentUser()
    !datDateOn = Date
    !datTimeOn = Time
    !strMachineName = (New_clsEnvironVariables.strComputerName)
  rs.Update
End With

rs.Close
DB.Close


ExitProcedure:
  Set rs = Nothing
  Set DB = Nothing
  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    New_clsErrorHandler.Unexpected mstrClass, "Logon"
  Resume ExitProcedure
End Sub
```

Comment: if you flip the table into design mode, does Access see the columns as the correct data type? You can (should) add  Time stamp column, and this is especially the case if you using the newer date/time types from sql server such as datetime2. IF you use the new datetime2 data types, then you have to link to sql using the native 11 or later - the default sql driver (the legacy one) will see  these columns as text.

Comment: Try to edit linked table through GUI, is it possible?